# Извлечь данные из тега alt и создав тег Title вписать в него данные из alt, массовая модификация в MySQL. Реально ли?

Tags: html, mysql, база-данных, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру :-)

Есть сайт Wordpress, в самих статьях размещён html код. Пример типового кода:

```
...<a href="/images/sample1.png" target="_blank" rel="highslide"><img class="aligncenter" src="/images/sample1.png" alt="Фото котика"></a>...

...<a href="/images/sample2.png" target="_blank" rel="highslide"><img class="aligncenter" src="/images/sample2.png" alt="Фото бабочки"></a>...
```

Необходимо в MySQL базе массово отредактировать их, а именно извлечь данные из тега alt и создав тег Title вписать в него данные из alt. Естественно в рамках блока, чтобы получилось так:

```
...<a href="/images/sample1.png" target="_blank" rel="highslide" title="Фото котика"><img class="aligncenter" src="/images/sample1.png" alt="Фото котика"></a>...

...<a href="/images/sample2.png" target="_blank" rel="highslide" title="Фото бабочки"><img class="aligncenter" src="/images/sample2.png" alt="Фото бабочки"></a>...
```

Это возможно командой MySQL? Или вообще как-либо возможно?

p.s.

**1)** *class="aligncenter"* может быть разным, к примеру, *class="aligncenter zagolovok"*

**2)** *samlpe1.png* является примером, имена файлов различны, но в рамках блока они практически всегда идентичны.

Comment: Это возможно. Хотелось бы увидеть либо цену за проект, либо Ваши наработки для решения.

Comment: Это мой блог, ему два месяца. Я просто почитал про оптимизацию для поисковиков и подумал что надо сделать всё по уму потому что всего несколько посетителей в день заходит  :-(

Comment: SEO - сложная вещь. И комплексная, тут сменой атрибутов не обойдёшься.

Comment: Главное не останавливаться и не опускать руки :-) Действуя методом проб и ошибок вполне можно добиться результатов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообще тут проще всего сделать простенький php скрипт, который выберет из базы все необходимые записи, которые требуется подправить, распарсит текст записи по шаблону <ссылка><картинка> или еще каким способом, но вытащит alt из картинок и вставит в title ссылки. но вообще, если записей меньше 100-300, тогда это проще и быстрее самому ручками это все исправить либо в базе, либо в редакторе cms.

Comment: Я так и сделал :-) В Notepad++ регулярное выражение: Найти `(highslide")(>.+?alt(=".+?"))` Изменить `$1 title$3$2`